# How can I update the buttons at only the row on which the button was clicked?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently when I click on any button, all edit buttons change to update buttons, but I just want to trigger the row where the action was actually performed without triggering any other button. I am using the below code snippet in my ReactJs project. can anyone please help in suggesting something that would work for me. Please note that I am not using hooks at this point.

```
import React from 'react';
    
    class GridSample extends React.Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          clicked: false,
        };
        this.handleOnedit = this.handleOnedit.bind(this);
        this.handleCancel = this.handleCancel.bind(this);
        this.handleUpdate = this.handleUpdate.bind(this);
      }
      handleOnedit = (event) => {
        const par = event.target.parentNode;
        const suppar = par.parentNode;
        suppar.setAttribute('contenteditable', true);
        suppar.focus();
        this.setState({ clicked: true });
      };
    
      handleOndelete() {
        alert('this is delete button');
      }
    
      handleCancel() {
        window.location.replace(false);
      }
    
      handleUpdate() {
        this.setState({
          clicked: false,
        });
      }
    
      render() {
        console.clear();
        return (
          <div>
            <table>
              <tr>
                <th>Firstname</th>
                <th>Lastname</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Action</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Jill</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>50</td>
                <td>
                  {!this.state.clicked ? (
                    <input type="button" value="Edit" onClick={this.handleOnedit} />
                  ) : (
                    <input
                      type="button"
                      value="Update"
                      onClick={this.handleUpdate}
                    />
                  )}
                  {this.state.clicked ? (
                    <input
                      type="button"
                      value="Cancel"
                      onClick={this.handleCancel}
                    />
                  ) : (
                    <input
                      type="button"
                      value="Delete"
                      onClick={this.handleOndelete}
                    />
                  )}
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Eve</td>
                <td>Jackson</td>
                <td>94</td>
                <td>
                  {!this.state.clicked ? (
                    <input type="button" value="Edit" onClick={this.handleOnedit} />
                  ) : (
                    <input
                      type="button"
                      value="Update"
                      onClick={this.handleUpdate}
                    />
                  )}
                  {this.state.clicked ? (
                    <input
                      type="button"
                      value="Cancel"
                      onClick={this.handleCancel}
                    />
                  ) : (
                    <input
                      type="button"
                      value="Delete"
                      onClick={this.handleOndelete}
                    />
                  )}
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>John</td>
                <td>Doe</td>
                <td>80</td>
                <td>
                  {!this.state.clicked ? (
                    <input type="button" value="Edit" onClick={this.handleOnedit} />
                  ) : (
                    <input
                      type="button"
                      value="Update"
                      onClick={this.handleUpdate}
                    />
                  )}
                  {this.state.clicked ? (
                    <input
                      type="button"
                      value="Cancel"
                      onClick={this.handleCancel}
                    />
                  ) : (
                    <input
                      type="button"
                      value="Delete"
                      onClick={this.handleOndelete}
                    />
                  )}
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
    
    export default GridSample;
```

Comment: Try rendering the table using an array to store Firstname, .. , this will make your code more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need to store your data in an array, it will help render something like a table:

```
const data = [
  { id: 1, firstName: 'Jill', lastName: 'Smith', age: 50 },
  { id: 2, firstName: 'Eve', lastName: 'Jackson', age: 94 },
  { id: 3, firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe', age: 80 },
];
```

So now you'll be able to render every row using `map`:

```
{data.map(({ id, firstName, lastName, age }) => (
  <tr key={id}>
    <td>{firstName}</td>
    <td>{lastName}</td>
    <td>{age}</td>
    <td>
      {this.state.updateId === id ? (
        <input
          type="button"
          value="Edit"
          onClick={this.handleOnedit}
        />
      ) : (
        <input
          type="button"
          value="Update"
          onClick={() => this.handleUpdate(id)}
        />
      )}
      {this.state.clicked ? (
        <input
          type="button"
          value="Cancel"
          onClick={this.handleCancel}
        />
      ) : (
        <input
          type="button"
          value="Delete"
          onClick={this.handleOndelete}
        />
      )}
    </td>
  </tr>
))}
```

To distinguish each row, you should have a state value like `updateId` to know which one you're editing:

```
this.state = {
  updateId: -1,
};
```

Checkout working example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-8aky3r

Answer (score 0):

You should try passing the index as a parameter and do the test on it instead of changing the value to true or false of your state.clicked (I added a link to an sandbox that uses your calss

```
import React from "react";

class GridSample extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      clicked: NaN,
      items: [
        { Firstname: "Jack", Lastname: "Ali", Age: 25 },
        { Firstname: "Adam", Lastname: "Alan", Age: 55 }
      ]
    };
    this.handleOnedit = this.handleOnedit.bind(this);
    this.handleCancel = this.handleCancel.bind(this);
    this.handleUpdate = this.handleUpdate.bind(this);
  }
  handleOnedit = (event, i) => {
    const par = event.target.parentNode;
    const suppar = par.parentNode;
    suppar.setAttribute("contenteditable", true);
    suppar.focus();
    this.setState({ ...this.state, clicked: i });
  };

  handleOndelete() {
    alert("this is delete button");
  }

  handleCancel() {
    window.location.replace(false);
  }

  handleUpdate(event, i) {
    this.setState({ ...this.state, clicked: i });
  }

  render() {
    console.clear();
    return (
      <div>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Action</th>
          </tr>
          {this.state.items.map((e, i) => {
            return (
              <tr key={i}>
                <td>{e.Firstname}</td>
                <td>{e.Lastname}</td>
                <td>{e.Age}</td>
                <td>
                  {!this.state.clicked === i ? (
                    <input
                      type="button"
                      value="Edit"
                      onClick={(event) => this.handleOnedit(event, i)}
                    />
                  ) : (
                    <input
                      type="button"
                      value="Update"
                      onClick={(event) => this.handleUpdate(event, i)}
                    />
                  )}
                  {this.state.clicked === i ? (
                    <input
                      type="button"
                      value="Cancel"
                      onClick={(event) => this.handleCancel(event, i)}
                    />
                  ) : (
                    <input
                      type="button"
                      value="Delete"
                      onClick={(event) => this.handleOndelete(event, i)}
                    />
                  )}
                </td>
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default GridSample;
```

Here is the example : https://codesandbox.io/s/react-class-forked-ze3o9?file=/index.js

Comment: Thanks @Zouhair, can you please help me with cancel event as well? I want to retain the last updated state and not the current changes.

Comment: @ShubhangiPant check the example I added the logic for the cancel button, and accepte the correct answers !

Comment: it didnt work for me.

Comment: @ShubhangiPant Check now, I forgot to save the changes :(